# what is difference between JspWriter and PrintWriter?

Tags: java, jsp

what is difference between JspWriter and PrintWriter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter.html):

> This abstract class emulates some of the functionality found in the java.io.BufferedWriter and java.io.PrintWriter classes, however it differs in that it throws java.io.IOException from the print methods while PrintWriter does not.

The `JspWriterImpl` of tomcat delegates the writing to the `PrintWriter` obtained from the response.